# eliminating, replacing or optimizing REGEXP from mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have two tables, `phone and phone_last_ten` (this contains the `last ten digits` of the original `phone` column).

I want to look for a list of numbers that wheather each of them is matching with the last ten digits of the phone numbers in database.

I have it working in `#4` snap but the performance is horrible as it cant use the index.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have used the `IN` keyword
Thanks to RhodiumToad on irc.freenode.com

[image]